# Print pyramid pattern

Tags: php

```
        1 
      1 2 1 
    1 2 3 2 1 
      1 2 1 
        1 

$newline = "\r\n";
 $prnt = '*';
 $nos = 3;
 for($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++)
 { 
    for($s = $nos; $s >= 1; $s--)
    {
        echo "&nbsp;";echo "&nbsp;";echo "&nbsp;";
    }
    for($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++)
    {
        echo $j;echo "&nbsp;";
    }
    $m = 2; 
    for($k = 1; $k <= ($i - 1); $k++)
    {  
            echo $k;echo "&nbsp;";


    }  

    echo '<br />';
    $nos--;
    }
    $nos = 1;

    for($i = 3; $i >= 1; $i--)
    {
      for ($s = $nos; $s >= 1; $s--) {
       echo "&nbsp;";echo "&nbsp;";echo "&nbsp;";
    }
    for($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++)
    {
        echo $j;echo "&nbsp;";
    }
    for($k = 1; $k <= ($i - 1); $k++)
    {
        echo $k;echo "&nbsp;";
    }
  $nos++;
  echo '<br />';//printf("\n");

 }
```

i got output

```
        1 
      1 2 1 
    1 2 3 1 2 
      1 2 1 
        1
```

1. am not able to print space when i use `echo ' ';` so i used  `echo "&nbsp;";` but i dont want to use `echo "&nbsp;";` plz resolve this issue.
2. I am  having problem creating above program but somewhere missing a value may be need apply some condition over there . Please see my code.

Comment: Is this homework? are you viewing it in a web browser?

Comment: Consecutive whitespace is collapsed in HTML.

Comment: Why not to use "&nbsp;" if it works?

Comment: yes...viewing it in a web browser

Comment: why are you defining `$newline = "\r\n"` and then using `echo '<br />'` everywhere?

Comment: @Bart: Or at least avoid *losing* points.  I'd take off points for any code i had to trace through to figure out what it's even *supposed* to do.  Proper variable names can help the code document itself.

Comment: Just because something appears to be a homework question doesn't mean that the question should be showered in downvotes. (Asker/voters alike) See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812 Not that this is a great question, just pointing that out.

Comment: I think the problem is not the homework, but the fact the contraints (and what is actually asked finally) are not clear. Why not to use <pre> or &nbsp;? Why not to explain it straight from the beginning (i'm referring to <pre> as it was clear for &nbsp;)?

Comment: @cHao I accidentally deleted my comment :'( If I were a teacher I would rather see beautiful code with mistakes then ugly code that works... For now.

Answer (score 2):

Printing multiple spaces in straight HTML isn't allowed because of how it must be rendered.

If you want to print exactly - whitespaces included - just wrap your code with a `<pre/>` tag.

```
<pre>Spacing    will be    literal.</pre>
```

You could also format with the `white-space` `CSS` property by setting it to `pre`.

```
.spaces {
    white-space: pre;
}

<div class="spaces">Spacing    will be    literal.</div>
```

Comment: I dont want to use <pre>

Comment: @Rajeshsonawane Any particular reason you don't want to?

Comment: `CSS` approach added.

Comment: `<pre>` isn't necessary, if you use a monospace font and `text-align: center`.  At that point, you don't even have to generate the pre-spaces to align stuff.

Comment: @cHao or just `text/plain`

Answer (score 0):

This is a fun little algorithm. Here's a recursive solution in PHP. I wrap it in <PRE> tag so that I can use spaces and new lines "\n".

```
<pre>
<?php
function printPyramid($height) {
    // initialize
    $size = ($height * 2) - 1;
    $half = $size / 2;
    $arr = Array();
    for($r = 0; $r < $size; $r++) {
        $arr[] = array();
        for($c = 0; $c < $size; $c++) {
            $arr[$r][] = "";
        }
    }
    $arr[$half][$half] = $height;
    // recursively build, pass array as reference "&"
    pyramidRec($arr, $half, $half, $size);
    // print
    for($r = 0; $r < $size; $r++) {
        for($c = 0; $c < $size; $c++) {
            if(empty($arr[$r][$c]))
                echo "  ";
            else if(strlen($arr[$r][$c]) == 1)
                echo "{$arr[$r][$c]} ";
            else
                echo $arr[$r][$c];
        }
        echo "\n";
    }    
}
function pyramidRec(&$arr, $r, $c, $size) {
    $val = $arr[$r][$c];
    $newVal = $val - 1;
    if($newVal == 0)
        return;
    // up
    if($r - 1 >= 0 && empty($arr[$r-1][$c])) {
        $arr[$r-1][$c] = $newVal;
        pyramidRec($arr, $r-1, $c, $size);
    }
    // down
    if($r + 1 < $size && empty($arr[$r+1][$c])) {
        $arr[$r+1][$c] = $newVal;
        pyramidRec($arr, $r+1, $c, $size);
    }  
    // left
    if($c - 1 >= 0 && empty($arr[$r][$c-1])) {
        $arr[$r][$c-1] = $newVal;
        pyramidRec($arr, $r, $c-1, $size);
    }
    // right
    if($c + 1 < $size && empty($arr[$r][$c+1])) {
        $arr[$r][$c+1] = $newVal;
        pyramidRec($arr, $r, $c+1, $size);
    }      
}

printPyramid(5);
?>
</pre>
```